# Get list of running processes

Tags: windows, r, process

I'm working on a Windows machine and would like to get the list of all running processes directly from R (basically process id and path to the program which is running).

I know `Sys.getpid()` gets me the process id of the current R process but does there also exist something to get me all processes running on the machine as I would get in Linux with `top` or `ps -x`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Thanks, I was too focussed around finding something in package base starting with Sys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tasklist`:

```
system2( 'tasklist' , stdout = TRUE )
  [1] ""                                                                            
  [2] "Nom de l'image                 PID Nom de la sessio Num‚ro de s Utilisation "
  [3] "========================= ======== ================ =========== ============"
  [4] "System Idle Process              0 Services                   0        24 Ko"
```

**EDIT** to get the R process:

```
grep("^rsession",readLines(textConnection(system('tasklist',intern=TRUE))),value=TRUE)
[1] "rsession.exe                  6772 Console                    1   387,420 Ko"
[2] "rsession.exe                  7984 Console                    1    48,436 Ko"
[3] "rsession.exe                  1272 Console                    1    80,572 Ko"
```

Comment: what about for a mac :)

Comment: `top` works in the terminal, sure, but not directly from R (error opening terminal: unknown)

Comment: for macOS Ventura 13 (2022):
  
  
  # for Rstudio:
  `suppressWarnings(grep("rsession",readLines(textConnection(system('top',intern=TRUE, timeout = 1))),value=TRUE))
# for R in Terminal
suppressWarnings(grep("\\<R\\>",readLines(textConnection(system('top',intern=TRUE, timeout = 1))),value=TRUE)) `